# Errors in Migrating models

Tags: python, django, django-models

Having errors in trying to migrate models(***makemigrations*** command). Errors in classes Cart and Product. Here's the code:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    type_status = (('Pending'), ('Ongoing'), ('Delivered'))
    type_payment = (('Yes'), ('No'))
    cart_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=type_status)
    payment_paid = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=type_payment)
    totalAmount = models.FloatField()

class Admin(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    itemName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Admin, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemName = models.ForeignKey(Admin, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Errors:
**registration.Cart.payment_paid: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
registration.Cart.status: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
registration.Product.itemName: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Admin.product_set' for 'registration.Product.itemName' clashes with reverse accessor for 'registration.Product.item_id'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'registration.Product.itemName' or 'registration.Product.item_id'. registration.Product.item_id: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Admin.product_set' for 'registration.Product.item_id' clashes with reverse accessor for 'registration.Product.itemName'.

HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'registration.Product.item_id' or 'registration.Product.itemName'**.

Comment: Refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015209/17562044) below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass tuples in your choices. You also need to set `max_length` at least as longest value in choices.

```
type_status = (('pending', 'Pending'), ('ongoing', 'Ongoing'), ('delivered', 'Delivered'))
type_payment = (('yes', 'Yes'), ('no', 'No'))
```

First string is a value that you keep in DB, second one is human-readable (that you will see in select input).

See [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Comment: The error regarding the tuples is now solved. The only errors that remain is in the Product class (with the HINTS). Any ideas?

Comment: @arsls you have two `ForeignKey` fields connecting to the same model. You need to set `related_name="some_name"` for one of them (or both, but use DIFFERENT names)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way that you did for choices:

Do like below code:

```
type_status = (
           ('Pending', 'Pending'), 
           ('Ongoing', 'Ongoing'), 
           ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
)
```

This error will solve And don't forget to give `max_length=100` in that model field where you added `CHOICES`

Comment: The error regarding the tuples is now solved. The only errors that remain is in the Product class (with the HINTS). Any ideas?

Comment: @arsls Refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015209/17562044) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give [**`ForeignKey.related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for both the foreign keys i.e. `item_id` and `itemName` whatever you want so that it will not clash:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Admin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="id_item")
    itemName = models.ForeignKey(Admin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="name_of_item")
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Then kindly run migrate commands.

> **Note:** Generally, fields of the models are writing in `pascal_case` so you may change it to `total_amount` from <s>`totalAmount`</s> in `Cart` model. Also it is not good practice to name same foreign keys in both the models.

Answer (score 0):

The Reverse Accessor error is caused by similar field names in `Admin` and `Product` models.

Change field names of `Product` model, or add `related_name` attribute and define a different name. (E.g. p_item_name, p_item_id)

sample code:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Admin, related_name="p_item_id", 
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemName = models.ForeignKey(Admin, related_name="p_item_name", 
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField()
```